# Laravel form helper with spam prevention

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 4.2 for a website. I want to protect all my forms from spam as well as csrf.
I was thinking of extending the form helper of laravel so that it automatically creates a hidden input field that must always be empty.Just like it creates a token field automatically for csrf.
Then I want to add a before filter like csrf filter on all post, put methods and check if this field is blank. If its not it is spam.
I dont know how to implement this. Where should i start?

Answer (score 0):

Here what are you searching...
https://github.com/msurguy/Honeypot

Comment: No I have seen that. In this package you have to manually add a honeypot field in every form and again check it in the controller. I want it to be handled automatically like csrf tokens are handled with a simple filter.

Comment: But csrf token you add to the form also, or ‘Form::open()‘ make it for you.

Comment: Yes 'Form::open () ' creates it automatically.

Comment: So, create macros for `Form` and put there Form::open and honeypot input